# Python check existing elements in list and find next value

Tags: python, python-2.7

Here is the command output:

```
 ab1.1 something
 ab2.1 something
 ab3.1 something
 ab4.1 something
```

I have below code to check existing entries.

```
  list1 = []
  for line in command_output.split("\n"):
      if line.stratswith("ab"):
          list1.append(line.split()[0])
```

check ab4.1 is present in list1 if not print ab4.1 is not present and use it.

If ab4.1 is already exist,  check with next available value that is  ab5.1. if not available in list1  print ab5.1 is not present in list1  and use it and so on.

To check element is not present i will use below condition

```
  if "ab4.1" not in list1:
      print "Use ab4.1"
  else:
      check another available value.
```

Please help me to find out another available value.

Comment: typo error in line.stratswith()......

Comment: Whats is command_output? is it a or input string? or a file input string?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should loop over numbers to find an available one. To check efficiently you should store the words in a `set`:

```
command_output = """ ab1.1 something
 ab2.1 something
 ab3.1 something
 ab4.1 something"""


first_words = set()
for line in command_output.split("\n"):
    first_words.add(line.split()[0])

for j in xrange(4, len(first_words) + 5):
    use = 'ab{}.1'.format(j)
    if not use in first_words:
        break
else:
    raise RuntimeError, 'impossible!'

print "using {}".format(use)
```

If you like you can shorten this a bit using comprehensions:

```
first_words = {line.split()[0].strip() for line in command_output.split("\n")}    
use = 'ab{}.1'.format((j for j in xrange(4, len(first_words) + 5)
                       if not 'ab{}.1'.format(j) in first_words).next())

print "using {}".format(use)
```

Comment: @abc We start at 4 and go up to len(first_words)+5. That way if need be we go through one more number than are already there. This guarantees that we will find an unused one.

Answer (score 0):

How about something like:

`lister = [adit1,adit2,adit3]
count = len(lister) + 1
lister.join('adit' + str(count))`

Answer (score 0):

If i am correct with your problem you can try like this:-

```
ls = ['a','b','c']
list1 = []
for i in ls:
    if i not in list1:
        print("Use {}".format(i))
```